# SQL Query required to calculate and agregate net payments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query that outputs all artist sales less commisions and sorts:

```
SELECT `exhibition_sales`.`Name`, `exhibition_sales`.`Category`,
       `exhibition_sales`.`Catologue_Number`, `exhibition_sales`.`Title`,
       `exhibition_sales`.`Quantity`, `exhibition_sales`.`Unit_Price`,
       `exhibition_sales`.Quantity*Unit_Price as `Total`,
       `exhibition_sales`.`Commision_Rate`,
       `exhibition_sales`.Quantity * Commision_Rate*Unit_Price as `Commision`,
       `exhibition_sales`.Quantity * Unit_Price - Quantity * Unit_Price * Commision_Rate as `Net_Receipt`
FROM exhibition_sales
ORDER BY `exhibition_sales`.`Name` ASC
```

I want to total the value of 'Net_Recepts' for each 'Name' where they have more than one sale.  I am happy for this to be done on the same output (Ideally) or in a new seperate query.

Comment: great, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

That is an easy one. Just group by *Name* and aggregate the wanted field:

```
SELECT `exhibition_sales`.`Name`,
       sum(`exhibition_sales`.Quantity * Unit_Price - Quantity * Unit_Price * Commision_Rate) as `Net_Receipt`
FROM exhibition_sales
group by `exhibition_sales`.`Name`
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you already have th total value of Net_Receipt so all you'd need to do would be add at the bottom this line and you should get what you are looking for
WHERE exhibition_sales > 1;

Comment: You can't compare to the table, just columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by and compare to an aggregate of the number of rows found.

```
SELECT 
    `Name`,
    `Category`,
    `Catologue_Number`,
    `Title`,
    `Quantity`,
    `Unit_Price`,
    (`Quantity` * `Unit_Price`) as `Total`,
    `Commision_Rate`,
    (`Quantity` * `Commision_Rate` * `Unit_Price`) as `Commision`,
    (`Quantity` * `Unit_Price`) - (`Quantity` * `Unit_Price` * `Commision_Rate`) as `Net_Receipt`
FROM `exhibition_sales`
GROUP BY `Name`
ORDER BY `Name` ASC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```